# Using Amazon EC2 with Baas

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine

I am looking for a back end web service interface for our mobile apps but also 
need to host a Ubuntu server behind this. Google seems to have an ideal solution
for this with their Compute and App engine, how do I do this with Amazon AWS. Reason being
is the Amazon EC2 has free tier.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to host web services on a Ubuntu server?

Comment: well not exactly, we don't have the skills to build a mobile backend so were looking for a solution like Google app engine, Parse, Kinvey but we need a Ubuntu server behind the web front end

Comment: Note that Google Cloud Platform has a [free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/) and supports [Ubuntu on GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems#ubuntu).